# Why is “ELL” the solution to the crossword clue "Loss Leader?"?

Tags: explanation, crossword-clues

I was doing a crossword from the [NY Times](https://downforacross.com/beta/play/23969) (from Tuesday, October 25, 2022 By Ashleigh Silveira, Nick Shephard / Will Shortz) and I got the following clue.

29 DOWN - Loss leader?

The answer is "ELL". However, I do not understand why and how "ELL" fits the clue.

Why is the answer "ELL" and how does the clue fit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leader (first letter) of "Loss" is L ("ELL").

Comment: A "loss leader" is a marketing term that refers to selling an item at a negative profit (loss) to bring in (lead) customers to the store in the hopes that they will buy other (positive profit) items, too.